# Regex Counting Characters in a text field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to count the characters in a text field. I found how to count all the characters.

```
string st = TextBox1.Text;
this.TextBox2.Text = Regex.Matches(st, ".|").Count.ToString();
```

But I  need to create 2 more separate counts, Any Caps, numbers, - or # up to (not including) @

`eg. LA-FG4-DETF-DJJJTHD-S@T-JHF-F1-F2` the count would be `21`

and the other one I need to count from the @ (including) , Any Caps, numbers, - or #  to the end of the text field.

`eg. LA-FG4-DETF-DJJJTHD-S@T-JHF-F1-F2` the count would be `12`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: string.Split and string.Length are too simple?

Comment: C# Preferably but either or would be great?

Comment: Sorry should have stated very new using regex.

Comment: By "Any Caps" do you mean you *only* want to count letters if they are capital letters or do you want to count all letters, both upper case and lower case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string input = "LA-FG4-DETF-DJJJTHD-S@T-JHF-F1-F2";
        int atIndex = input.IndexOf('@');
        int count1 = Regex.Matches(input.Substring(0, atIndex), "[0-9A-Z#-]").Count;
        int count2 = Regex.Matches(input.Substring(atIndex, input.Length - atIndex), "[0-9A-Z#@-]").Count;
```